# How to clearly see what is process and spot colors in the swatches palette

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pantone, swatches

## How can you clearly see the differences between process and spot colors in the swatches palette in Illustrator?

I have issues seeing which are spot colors and which are process colors. Is there a simple way to see the difference?

Besides these little triangle things.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## You sure can!

Just click on the menu button in the top left corner and change it to small list view or large list view. This will even allow you to see the perecentage of each CMYK color!

Note: CMYK percentage is only there if the swatch was created with "name using color values" was checked. Viewing as list will not always show color breakouts

[image]

Comment: Note that the CMYK percentage is only there if the swatch was created with "name using color values" was checked. Viewing as list will *not* always show color breakouts.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the info :) I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to viewing the swatches as a list....

Spot colors swatches have a **spot** on them.....

[image]

- Standard process swatches have no corner indicator.
- Global colors have a white triangle in the lower right corner.
- Spot colors have a white triangle with a spot on it in the lower right corner.